# Bypass UAC with Python 3

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, uac

I'm tried to apply the code:

```
import subprocess as Popen
import subprocess as sp

pswd="P4ssW0rd"
prog = sp.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:domain\romanuser', cmd.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE)
prog.stdin.write(pswd.encode() )
prog.communicate()
```

To open a cmd windows with admin privileges.

I'm receiving back:

```
omanuser: ssword for domain
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to acquire user password
```

Does anyone have an idea if is possible to use a function to pass this password to the second line in the shell?

I'm very new in Python.

Best regards,

RC

Comment: I have just see that I cannot use '\r' to the first letter of my admin user.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not recognize very well the '\r' at the line as the begin of my user. I only change \r for \R and the username of my admin account was detected correctly and I obtain the result I wanted.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`\r` has special meaning inside an ordinary `str` literal: it represents a carriage return.

You can use a raw string literal

```
prog = sp.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', r'/user:domain\romanuser', cmd.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE)
```

or escape the backslash

```
prog = sp.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:domain\\romanuser', cmd.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE)
```